# Python application deployment

Tags: python

I want to deploy my python application to my customers.  Well, I basically don't know much about python application deployment, but my requirements/questions are

1) The user can install it as long as they can access internet.  For mac applications, they are all hosted by apple app store.  For chrome extensions, they are hosted by google.  My question is, if there's a similar place that are hosting python applications, and it provides updating mechanism?  If I have to do it on my own, is there any existing framework stuff for me to do it?

2) My application would be used to read USB device, and act as a http server.  I want the install package to be as small as possible, and I also need to package python runtime.  What is the package size that I should be expecting?  5M? 10M?

Comment: These are really multiple questions, some of which are covered in the Python online documentation. USB will require Python modules not part of the standard library, and HTTP might. Package size will depend on the operating system and the way of installation. Also have a look at [pypi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have sucesfully used pyinstaller for my project

https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/wiki

My application is reasonably large, so the installer package is around 100MB which compresses to 60MB. A lot of that is numpy, qt, scipy, and matplotlib.

We use a script to invoke pyinstaller which packages our main script and dependencies into a .app file. https://github.com/Erotemic/ibeis/blob/next/installers.py
If you are installing on a mac, this script in my repo will take a pyinstaller package and bundle it into a dmg. 
https://github.com/Erotemic/ibeis/blob/next/_scripts/mac_dmg_builder.sh

If you host your program on your own server you can integrate an auto-update mechanism, but I don't know how to do that exactly. I just host my installers on dropbox.